# Can a number of the form $n = {2^r}{b^2}$ always be represented as a sum of two squares, if $r \geq 1$ and $b$ is an odd composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Can a number of the form $n = {2^r}{b^2}$ always be represented as a sum of two squares, if $r \geq 1$ and $b$ is an odd composite?

More generally:

> Can a number of the form $n = {2^r}{b^2}$ always be represented as a sum of two squares, if $r \geq 1$?

Comment: Can we say that $2^{2m}b^2=0^2+(2^mb)^2$ is represented as a sum of two squares?

Comment: @mathlove, well yes.  What else do you have in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because
$$2^{2m+1}b^2=(2^mb)^2+(2^mb)^2$$
and
$$2^{2m}b^2=0^2+(2^mb)^2$$